# how can I get a custom data in response while sending bulk mails using mandrillApp API?

Tags: php, mandrill

if I want custom data (ex. user_id) in a response message call from mandrill API right now I am getting response now like

```
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "status": "sent",
    "_id": "Some Hash Id",
    "reject_reason": null
```

can I get user_id in response?

or any other way from I can fetch this custom data (user_id) with respect to every recipient while sending bulk mails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mandrill API won't return any custom data in the API response. Instead, you'd need to store the relationship between the email address and the user id information that you're passing, and then use the Mandrill-generated ID to relate that information to the emails being sent by Mandrill.

You can use webhooks to get information sent back to you on certain Mandrill events, like sending, opens, clicks, bounces, etc. Webhook payloads will include the recipient data, and the message ID (like what's returned in the API call). You can also use [custom message metadata](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21786413-Using-Custom-Message-Metadata) to pass your own unique information that will be included when you get the webhook data back. It still won't be in the original API response, but you can use this to relate information back to your system if needed.

Comment: Okay...Thank you Kaitlin... :)